# Laravel prevent adding too many additional relations

Tags: php, laravel, scopes

I have a model called `Transfer` and a model called `Account`, and two relations in my `Transfer` model:

```
public function outgoing()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'outgoing_id');
}

public function incoming()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'incoming_id');
}
```

This is used to transfer money from my bank account to my wallet for example, or from my credit card to my bank, and so on..

So an account can have a few types. For instance, `bank` can be an account type. Now if I want to grab all outgoing bank related transfers, by using the actual name `bank`, I have to use an additional relation, for example:

```
public function outgoingbank()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'outgoing_id')->where('type', 'bank');
}
```

And to grab all outgoing transfers that are `bank` transfers, I can now use this:

```
auth()->user()->transfers()->has('outgoingbank')->get();
```

But my question is, is there a better way to do this with for example query scopes in my `Account` model, instead of adding an additional relation for each `account type`? Or perhaps an accessor in my `Transfer` model?

Comment: Might this be better as a `manyToMany` relationship? `outgoing_id`, `incoming_id`,  `type` for example? Would basically be a pivot between two records in the `accounts` table, and you could use `->withPivot(["type"]);` when querying the relationship. Hard to say; there's an argument for having `transfers` act as the pivot, and its own model.

Comment: Have to think about that one yes, since it's just really a `oneToMany` relationship, since every transfer can only have one `incoming_id` and one `outgoing_id`. But it might be a good solution to this problem, although I think it should be easily possible to solve it without having to go the "pivot way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using whereHas, which just popped into my brain all of a sudden:

```
$bank_transfers = auth()->user()->transfers()->with('outgoing')->whereHas('outgoing', function ($query){
        return $query->where('type', 'bank');
    })->get();
```